# how to autofill and enable submit and retrieve results from an external website

Tags: javascript, asp.net

For example there is external website to check the name of person from registration number.Now I want to write a code where I start with specific number and increment it and each time fetch the record and store details in excel.My main issue is I dont wanna manually sit and type all the numbers in external website.I start with a number and automatically a code should increment number each time and fetch records.

Answer (score 0):

OKay, use a static variable/session variable(Preferably static one); And set a default value to that variable; Then increment the value whenever the user passes the registration phase..

Eg:

Static string regNum="RN1000";
 /* Make  required operations , if valid then proceed */
 regNum="RN"+(Convert.ToInt64(regNum.TrimStart('R').TrimStart('N'))+1).ToString();

This sort of condition could help you out.. :)

Comment: I cant create any variable as i wanna access data from external website.Filling up data through a code from different domain

Comment: For example there is a website www.xyz.com owned by you.I dono any thing else about website except url to use.Now i wanna write a code which can fill data in your website form and get me results